# Зачем нужен тип окна Dekstop PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Зачем нужен тип окна Dekstop, если подобное окно не отображается на экране? Как таким образом можно взаимодействовать с рабочим столом?

Comment: пожалуйста, объясните лучше что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Да сделать я ничего и не хочу, просто момент заинтересовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип окна Qt::Desktop    `0x00000010 | Window`   указывает что это виджет типа [QDesktopWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html).

QDesktopWidget не совсем виджет, скорее интерфейс к рутовому окну. Нужен был (сейчас не рекомендуется) для того чтоб узнать геометрию экранов и мониторов.